# Get a reference to status menu item and change its title

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I have a Mac OS app with a status menu (made in Interface Builder). I want to change status **menu item title** when certain event happens. I can do it just fine inside the action handler, because I have a reference to the item there (`sender`):

```
- (IBAction)playPauseMusic:(id)sender {
  // ...
  [sender setTitle:@"New Title"];
}
```

But how to do it in other parts of my app? I don't know how to get a reference to `menuItem` in the following code:

```
- (void) someOtherMethod:(int)isPlaying {
    menuItem = ...;
    if(isPlaying) {
        [menuItem setTitle:@"Pause"];
    }
}
```

What to do to make the above work?

**Update.** Here's how I attach the status menu:

```
// MyAppDelegate.h:

@interface MyApp : NSApplication
@end

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
  NSMenu *statusMenu;
  NSStatusItem *statusItem;
  // ...
}
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
// ...
@end

// MyAppDelegate.m:

@synthesize statusMenu;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]
        statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setMenu:[self statusMenu]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I created an outlet for the menu item *in Xcode*. I followed the ["Create and connect a new outlet"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW10) video guide. I made a `strong` outlet for my menu item:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *playMenuItem;
```

Then added it to the interface:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate ...
{
    // ...
    NSMenuItem *playMenuItem;
}
```

Then added `@synthesize` declaration in implementation:

```
@synthesize playMenuItem;
```

Finally, the following worked:

```
[playMenuItem setTitle:@"New Title"];
```

P.S. If anyone can show me how to make it simpler, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access an item within the menu, then set a tag on the menu item (in IB, for example) and use:

```
NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[statusItem menu] itemWithTag:100];    // 100 = example
menuItem.title = @"Something";
```

If the code that wants to set the title is not the same object that holds `statusItem` then you'll need to expose a `setStatusMenuTitle:forItemWithTag:` method which performs the above code.

I cannot tell you how to get access to *that* object without more details, however.

Comment: No, because the statusItem is the item for the whole menu

Comment: @ash OK, I guess you mean you want to modify a menu item within the menu.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: I figured out and posted my solution here (with outlets) at the same time you offered yours. I'm not sure what solution is better. Yours is shorter, but requires arbitrary numeric tag.

Comment: Fortunately, it's all inside one MyAppDelegate object.

Comment: @ash If both work then both are fine.  I think my solution would only have an advantage if the menu is dynamically created or if the menu appears in more than one place (like a context menu, for example).